# How do I change state from a map loop?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I created a "skillProg" state using useState and want to change it using the "setSkillProg" inside a map loop. But I get a unexpected token error. Here is the code:

```
 const Skills = () => {
  const skills = [
    { bgcolor: "#0bd30e", completed: 100, name: "HTML" },
    { bgcolor: "#0bd30e", completed: 100, name: "CSS" },
    { bgcolor: "#0bd30e", completed: 90, name: "JavaScript" },
    { bgcolor: "#0bd30e", completed: 90, name: "React" },
    { bgcolor: "#0bd30e", completed: 90, name: "Express" },
    { bgcolor: "#0bd30e", completed: 90, name: "MongoDB" },
    { bgcolor: "#0bd30e", completed: 90, name: "Firebase" },
    { bgcolor: "#0bd30e", completed: 90, name: "PostGreSQL" },
    { bgcolor: "#0bd30e", completed: 90, name: "Git" },
    { bgcolor: "#0bd30e", completed: 90, name: "JavaScript" },
  ];
  const [skillProg, setSkillProg] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div className="skills">
      {skills.map((skill, idx) => (
        {setSkillProg({skill.completed})}
        <ProgressBar
          key={idx}
          bgcolor={skill.bgcolor}
          completed={skillProg}
          name={skill.name}
          className="progress_bar"
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Skills;
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO!  What exactly is your error?  What line is it pointing to?

Comment: You should not set state inside JSX, it will re-render the component infinite times

Comment: Hi, adding to @YatinGaikwad's comment, look at your arrow functions, the syntax is not correct because you are using `(` and not returning a JSX.. read more about arrow functions https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

also share what errors your editor is showing you.

Comment: so `... => (<Progress...` should work without adding. see how its used in reactJS https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#arrow-function-in-render

Answer (score 0):

When working with JSX elements in ReactJS, you typically return these values when working in `map()` (as well as when working within `render()`).  Try this...

```
return(
    <ProgressBar
      key={idx}
      bgcolor={skill.bgcolor}
      completed={skillProg}
      name={skill.name}
      className="progress_bar"
    />
);
```

Take a look at the default syntax from [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), you'll see the `return()` there, too...

```
let newArray = arr.map(callback(currentValue[, index[, array]]) {
  // return element for newArray, after executing something
}[, thisArg]);
```

Even though it's not JSX or ReactJS, it's still returning something.

P.S. I have asked for further debugging details, I will update my answer as needed when I get these.